# Moved project files into sub-directory, github still looks at upper level folder

Tags: github

I moved all of my project files from

```
x/project/files
```

to

```
x/project/sub-project/files
```

Github still uploads x/project/sub-project/files. How do I make upload sub-project/files instead?

I'm using pycharm if that helps at all

Edit 1:

I moved them using windows file explorer. I did commit before pushing

Edit 2: Solved by making a new GitHub repository.

Comment: How did you move the files? Did you commit that change before pushing?

Comment: I moved them using windows file explorer. I did commit before pushing

Comment: So you have a local commit that shows all the files being moved to the subfolder? Did that commit get included when you pushed to GitHub?

Comment: Yes. All the files are in the sub-project folder on github. The problem is that now on github there is project/sub-project/files instead of sub-project/files. My original question was unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed By making a new GitHub repository